# UIFont error in Xcode beta 7.3 (7D162j)?

Tags: xcode, swift, uifont

When compiling my project in the latest Xcode beta I get the following error.

[image]

The line of code that causes it is this:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10.0)
```

I am not sure how to fix this.

Any idea?

So here's more context:

```
private lazy var view: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 80))
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10.0)
        label.font = font
        return view
    }()
```

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the line of code? Can you show more context?

Comment: If that's really the line, then it looks like 7.3 beta has a bug.  Please report a RADAR.  Maybe changing to `let font: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10.0)` would help.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Xcode -- work around it by trying equivalent lines until you find one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Yep I had this same problem too. Nothing worked for me until I tried initializing UIFont with UIFontDescriptor. So your code now would look like:

```
private lazy var view: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 80))
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10.0)
    let font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 10.0)
    label.font = font
    return view
}()
```

Also you might need to clean & rebuild your project after this change, the Xcode compiler didn't recognize the change at first.